# Changing number format based on value, within one cell

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel 2016 table that lists weights in pounds. For entries that are 2000 pounds or greater, I want to convert to tons and add a "tons" suffix. So the data:

```
500  1000  2000   3000
```

Would appear as:

```
500  1000  1 ton  1.5 tons
```

Right now, I have the numerical data in several hidden columns, with a formula in the visible columns that formats the data as desired. Is that the best way to do this, or can it be done with only a single set of columns? I've looked at custom number formats and conditional formatting, but they don't seem to be able to do the thing I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one column with the following formula:

`=IF(A1>1999,IF(A1/2000>1,ROUND(A1/2000,1)&" tons", ROUND(A1/2000,1)&" ton"),A1)`

2000 pounds = 1 ton
A1 is where the initial value is (your initial data)
The formula tests if the number in A1 is > 1999 (nearly 1 ton) convert the number to ton or tons (if >1)
Else it will write the same number

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, using a formula in a second column to format the data in the first column. I was wondering if there was a way to use custom number formats or conditional formatting to format the data within a single column. It sounds like there isn't.

Comment: Use the formula and copy paste special value to another column and delete the column you don't need later